# Proof of uniqueness of radix representation

Tags: elementary-number-theory

I am trying to understand the proof the following statement:

Let $p\ge2$ be a fixed natural number. Then, every natural number $a$ can be uniquely represented in the form: $$a=c_np^n+c_{n-1}p^{n-1}+\dots+c_1p+c_0,$$ where $c_n>0, 0\le c_i<p,\forall i=0,1,\dots,n$.

There's something I cannot understand at all:

Uniqueness:

Let's suppose we have two distinct representations:
$$a=c_np^n+\dots+c_0,c_n>0,0\le c_i<p$$

$$a=b_np^n+\dots+b_0,b_n>0,0\le b_i<p$$

$\Rightarrow p | b_0-c_0 \Rightarrow b_0=c_0$

$$\Rightarrow c_np^n + \ldots + c_1 = b_np^n + \ldots + b_1 \Rightarrow p | b_1 - c_1 \Rightarrow b_1 = c_1 \text{ and so on.} 
$$

I don't understand what's going on in the proof. How do we conclude that $p$ divides $b_0-c_0$ and how does this mean that $b_0=c_0$? What do we do next?

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151066/discussion-on-question-by-saq-proof-of-uniqueness-of-radix-representation); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.